# Wifi controller disappears randomly at times and can only bring it back rebooting

Tags: wireless

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T14, running Ubuntu 22.04. Since I had this laptop this is a recurring problem, and I don't know if it's a OS problem or a hardware problem. Every now and then the wifi controller goes down. It disconnects from the internet, it does not show any available networks and turning it off and on again does nothing. Only rebooting the laptop fixes it. I have yet to find out a pattern on when/how this happens, sometimes it can happen 5 times a day, other times not happen for a week. I'd like to ask help debugging this problem, what I test when it's up and when it's down so that I can find out if it's a software problem that can be fixed by an update or downgrade, or a hardware problem and I have to send it back. Thanks!

Edit: I'm running the 5.15.0-58-generic kernel, and details of the network controller are

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0090]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    IOMMU group: 9
    Region 0: Memory at 603d1cc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Firstly open a terminal and type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`then let know which one you are booting e.g. linux-image-5.19.0-21-generic then type `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` and edit your question above, pasting in the text for us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the original post

Comment: OK try this. Go here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html and download the 5.10+ compressed folder iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0 then extract it and copy all 3 files into your /lib/firmware folder then reboot. If you don't know how to do that with the command line then let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and since then I have not seen the issue happen again in the last ~month. It seems that it is now fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: That's good to hear @tegonzalo if you believe this is what fixed your problem then please accept the answer below so that people with the same problem can find a question with an answer when they search here on askubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) and download the 5.10+ compressed folder iwlwifi-ty-59.601f3a66.0 then extract it and copy all 3 files into your /lib/firmware folder then reboot.